# In Supernatural were Leviathans created before Archangels or after Archangels?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural so far according to my understanding first Leviathans were created by God(in possible hope to defeat Darkness) but then when God saw their destructiveness he casted and locked them away in the purgatory. Then he went to create Archangels and with their help he finally defeated and locked away Darkness. But according to [Supernatural Wiki page](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=God#11.20_Don.27t_Call_Me_Shurley) god first created Archangels, defeated and locked away Darkness and then he created Leviathans. More specifically according to the page:

> Eventually, God would go on to create the archangels, and along with
>   them would trick the Darkness by locking His sister away

and then:

> With His sister locked away, God began His first attempt at unfettered
>   creation, He would go on to create the first beasts, the Leviathans.
>   However, God became concerned at their destructiveness, and locked
>   them away in Purgatory

I thought that Leviathans were Gods oldest creations to exist (though locked away in purgatory) but it appears Archangels were created before them. Which one is the older among them - Archangels or Leviathans?

Comment: I have some catching up to do, but Gods sister?

Comment: @Peter If upto haven't been upto latest episodes then probably this question became a spoiler for you ;) . Catchup soon :)

Comment: Wikis are frequently wrong, as they are generally publicly editable.  I'd trust something said on-screen (as long as the character could be relied on to be being mostly honest) over something that's unsourced from a wiki.  If it's in a wiki and sourced, evaluate the source.

Answer (score 6):

Leviathan came before angels, Cas states "long before my kind God created leviathans". They were like a scarier version of angels; a trial run almost.

From the [Wiki](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Leviathans):

> **Long before God created angel and man, he made the first beasts** **-- the**
>   **Leviathans.** I personally found them entertaining, but he was concerned
>   they'd chomp the entire petri dish, so he locked them away. Why do you
>   think he created Purgatory? To keep those clever, poisonous things
>   out.
> <sub>— [Death](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Death) on the Leviathans in *[Meet the New
>   Boss](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Meet_the_New_Boss)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

God created Archangels first from the primordial energy. He along with the archangels then sealed away Amara (the darkness). After sealing her, God then created the Leviathans to whom he entrusted the mark of Cain. After the leviathans became corrupted with its power, God bound the leviathans in purgatory and passed the mark of Cain to Lucifer. Lucifer too got corrupted, got himself put into the cage and the mark was finally passed to Cain.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you provide evidence for this?  It answers the question, but so does the linked wiki article in the question; the person asking the question is requesting evidence.  Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Supernatural universe is inconsistent in later seasons so there might not be a good answer.

You could argue that:

- Amara is older than Death since she says in Season 11 Episode 1 that she doesn't know Death,
- Archangels helped God seal Amara, so they must have existed before Death,
- Death states in "Meet the New Boss" that he found Leviathans entertaining, which implies that Death has existed at the same time as they did,
- hence Archangels predate Leviathans, because Archangels predate Death and supposedly Death predates Leviathans. However, it's still possible for Death to come into existence after Leviathans have been created and this argument breaks.

You could also argue that this doesn't hold since Death states that it might be older than God (Season 5, during the first Dean and Death scene). While I find it plausible that neither Death nor God remembers who's older (as they might have existed outside the time itself), I find it rather implausible that Death knows about Amara but doesn't remember that it hasn't existed before her.

Lore-wise Archangels probably predate Leviathans, but I suggest to not get into the lore details after Season 5.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was just about the Leviathan and the Archangels, not about Death.  You merely state "Archangels predate Leviathans" but since that was the question you need to provide some support for that.

Answer (score -1):

I think there was nothing before God and Amara. Then he created Archangels and locked Amara. Then he created Earth and low life on it. And a little later Leviathans and Lilith. But they failed and he locked them up too.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence for your answers?

Answer (score -1):

It says that god created the first beasts the Leviathans. The archangels were the first beings of Light besides God himself, but they are not beasts.

Comment: So which was created first?

Comment: @blackwood, leviathans as angels were not beasts, says it quite clearly in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think the leviathans were created, after the archangels. Death said that God was afraid, they would chomp the whole petri dish. Meaning that other things were around with them. Amara would have to be locked away for other things to be around, as she always destroyed everything. This would mean the Archangels are older, as they helped lock her away. Thats just my opinion, I dont know if it's true.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Pleat take our [tour] to see  [answer] on the site. Try to have context from the source material to support your opinion.